# MySQL - consistent select and update by two concurrent processes

Tags: mysql

I have a program task to perform the consistent updates of table. For simplicity I'll talk about the dummy tables just to show the idea. So I have two tables: `user` and `note`.

The `note` has an `id` (primary key auto increment) and `user_id` (foreign key), `number` and `next_number`.
The `number` is a number of user's note. The `next_number` can be equal to `0` if this is a latest user's note or can be equal to number of next user's note (like a pointer to next node in C++ linked list).
So each user has notes numbered from 1 to n.

Now some two processes (**Proc1** and **Proc2**) have a need to insert the row to table `note` for same user.

So each of that processes is starting a transaction, retrieving the `number` of latest user's note, then performing some other actions and inserting new row with `number` incremented to 1.

Is it possible that both processes (**Proc1** and **Proc2**) will **retrieve** same `number` inside their transactions (say first process will perform `SELECT` statement before second process will perform its `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements)?

For example:

1. Proc1: `SELECT number FROM note WHERE user_id = 1 AND next_number = 0` - retrieved number **5**
2. Proc2: `SELECT number FROM note WHERE user_id = 1 AND next_number = 0` - retrieved number **5**
3. Proc1: `INSERT INTO note SET number = 6, next_number = 0, user_id = 1, text = 'Proc1 note'`
4. Proc2: `INSERT INTO note SET number = 6, next_number = 0, user_id = 1, text = 'Proc2 note'`
5. Proc1: `UPDATE note SET next_number = 6 WHERE number = 5`
6. Proc2: `UPDATE note SET next_number = 6 WHERE number = 5`
7. Proc1: commiting the transaction of Proc1
8. Proc2: commiting the transaction of Proc2

If it's possible, how to avoid this?
Will the [**`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) solve the issue?

**UPDATE - simplifying my question**

So the general question is *if the process started a transaction how to disallow other MySQL sessions to interact with the rows which the current transaction is working with?*

Comment: It is good idea to make the 'note' column also auto increment. Then use  update not set next_number=(select last_insert_id()) where next_number = 0;  Of course, need to do the whole thing in a transaction.

Comment: The auto increment ensures the uniqueness of generated values, but not a correct sequence. There is no any guarantee that it will generate a `1,2,3` sequence and not a `1,3,4`. Also in my case the `note` table contains the notes of different users. So the auto increment is not a way here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should test this to make sure it's doing the right thing, but the second `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` statement should block until the first is done.  You should also look at the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level which sets this implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, [Joshua](http://stackoverflow.com/users/211760/). Can you explain your answer better, especially taking into account the question in my **UPDATE**?
Also I have to say that the testing you've mentioned could be a bit difficult in my application, so it's better to know which exact approach is correct in this case.

Comment: Whichever transaction first executes `...LOCK IN SHARE MODE` should hold those rows until the transaction is finished.  To test this, I would open two connections to the server.  Start the first transaction, then  try to run the second transaction.  It should block until the first one is completed.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Seems I need to write some multithreading Java application which will run transactions in parallel not synchronized threads with `SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. I'll notify you about the results and will accept the answer if it's working well.